# matplotlib - Plot 2D map data using Python and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot map data given in CSV format for performing robot localization. I have a numpy 2D array called `map` which indexes onto the probability value that the robot is at that grid position.

E.g. `map[500, 375] = 0.75` means there is a 75% chance of the robot being at grid `500, 375`.

Currently I am using matplotlib's `surface_plot` function to plot a 3D height map, but I wish to use matplotlib to plot a 2D color map where instead of height, the probability is represented by a particular color.

Any ideas on how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm not sure if it's what you need but I think you might want to take a look at [`plt.imshow()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow). It has a large variety of colormaps.

For example to plot something using a `hot-cmap`:

```
plt.imshow(map, origin='lower', cmap="hot", interpolation='none')
```

The parameters are actually not very important, the `origin` is (from my perspective) confusing that `0,0` is top left by default and you need to specify `'lower'` if you want `0,0` to be bottom left. The interpolation can be omitted if you *want* some kind of interpolation but if you don't want any then you need to define it as `'none'`.

A list of all possible colormaps can be found in one of matplotlibs [example codes](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).